# Formatting double by enforcing decimal separator

Tags: c#

I am searching a way to format a double into a string that match this rules:

> The encoding shall consist of a ***decimal mantissa*** optionally followed by a ***decimal exponent***.
>
> The ***decimal mantissa*** consists of an optional plus sign "+" or minus sign "­-", followed by a sequence of one or more digits, followed by a full
>   stop ".", followed by a sequence of zero or more digits.
>
> A ***decimal exponent*** consists of the latin capital letter E optionally followed by a plus
>   sign "+" or minus sign "-­", followed by one or more digits.

```
Valid expressions:
+0.0E0
0.0E­0
1.5
32.178E+02
0.25E8
0.E25
2.
5.0

Invalid expressions:        Problem:
1.2E3.                      Decimal point not allowed in exponent
1E05                        Decimal point required in mantissa
1,000.00                    Comma not allowed
3.E                         Digit(s) required in exponent
.5                          At least one digit must precede the decimal point
1                           Decimal point required in mantissa
```

The main difficulty is to **enforce decimal separator** and preserving double precision and exponent notation.

```cs
(2d).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
// returns "2"
// needed "2."
(2E+20d).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
// returns "2E+20"
// needed "2.E+20"
(-2E-20d).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
// returns "-2E-20"
// needed "-2.E-20"
// ETC...
```

I suppose Regex would be the easier way to transform the ToString(...) representation but I would like to implement my own formating function directly based on double value (not on representation).

Any help will be welcome.

Edit after Sinatr comment:

In addition,

> The encoding have to keep the smallest representation as possible because of large amount of number represented.

Comment: Have you tried [`ToString("E")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-exponential-e-format-specifier)? Or [custom format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) ?

Comment: Sorry, I can add this rule: I would like to keep the smallest representation as possible because of large amount of number represented. `1d.ToString("E")` returns `1.000000E+000`, I need `1.` representation instead. Custom format strings did not help me.